# Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in Observer

Tags: magento-1.9

I tried to change the **attribute value** once we click on **Delete** button present in cart page :

[image]

**config.xml**  :

```
<sales_quote_remove_item>
    <observers>
        <example_delete_from_cart>
            <class>Amasty_Example_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>DeleteFromCart</method>
        </example_delete_from_cart>
    </observers>
</sales_quote_remove_item>
```

**app/code/local/Amasty/Example/Model - Observer.php**

```
public function DeleteFromCart($observer) 
{ 
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
        array($product->getId()),
        array('cart_status' => 0),
        $storeId = 0
    );
}
```

**Result**

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in line:`@`array($product->getId()),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
public function DeleteFromCart($observer) 
{ 
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem()->getProduct();
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
        array($product->getId()),
        array('cart_status' => 0),
        $storeId = 0
    );
}
```

Comment: Could you pls help me with my post: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/284557/57334